# Updating variables in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I set `lower_case_table_names = 2` in my.cnf file. After setting the variable I restarted mysql server, but still the value is 0, when I use `SHOW VARIABLES`.

I'm using MySQL 5.5. Any Ideas what else needs to be done?

**UPDATE**

my.cnf is at `/etc` and `/etc/mysql` (ubuntu OS)

content:-

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
lower_case_table_names = 2
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most obvious posibilities:

- error in **my.cnf** -- I would need to see exactly what is in your my.cnf file
- **my.cnf** is in the wrong location
- mysql server doesn't read **my.cnf** because of the command-line settings
- mysql server overrides the settings from **my.cnf** with the command-line settings

Show what's in your **my.cnf** file, what's its path, and how exactly you restart the server, and I will ellaborate on my answer.

**UPDATE:** You shouldn't use value "2" on UNIX (or any system that has case-sensitive file system)

From the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> If you are using MySQL on only one platform, you do not normally have
>   to change the **lower_case_table_names** variable from its default value.
>   However, you may encounter difficulties if you want to transfer tables
>   between platforms that differ in file system case sensitivity. For
>   example, on Unix, you can have two different tables named **my_table** and
>   **MY_TABLE**, but on Windows these two names are considered identical. To
>   avoid data transfer problems arising from lettercase of database or
>   table names, you have two options:
>
> Use **lower_case_table_names=1** on all systems. The main disadvantage
>   with this is that when you use **SHOW TABLES** or **SHOW DATABASES**, you do
>   not see the names in their original lettercase.
>
> Use **lower_case_table_names=0** on **Unix** and **lower_case_table_names=2** on
>   **Windows**. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names.
>   The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements
>   always refer to your database and table names with the correct
>   lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where
>   lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is
>   incorrect.
>
> **Exception**: If you are using **InnoDB** tables and you are trying to avoid
>   these data transfer problems, you should set **lower_case_table_names** to
>   **1** on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase.

What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to set it to 2?

Comment: I've updated the question with my.cnf content and also its location. I've tried both `/etc/init.d/mysql start or stop` and MySQL Workbench to restart servers. You mention about **command-line settings**, how to verify these settings?

Comment: Some people start the server with a script or through a command line. If you start it as a service, you don't have any command line parameters; only my.cnf

Comment: I can set it to 1 as well. But the problem is it doesn't get updated. It is always 0. I'm not sure how the setting in my.cnf is getting overridden.

Comment: MySQL silently ignores lower_case_table_names=2 on Ubuntu, set it to 0 or 1.

Comment: what's the contents of /etc/mysql/conf.d/ ? If you check the last line, you will see that everything in that folder gets included at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the my.cnf location is dependent on the way you have installed your mysql server.
I had a similar issue, set lower_case_table_names=1 in /etc/mysql/ dir. By mysql was picking it up. 
The problem was way I had installed it. I had downloaded xampp zip and unzipped it at /opt/ .
If you have done the same you need to add the variables to my.cnf to

```
/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

code looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
user        = nobody
port        = 3306
...
```

Hope this helps