# mysqli_fetch_object doesn't return accents in strings from some tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to get my head around. 
When I pull object from a certain table 'articles' from our MySQL database the characters with accents (like é á ú etc..) get turned into questionmarks. However when I pull from a different table 'highlights' this doesn't happen.

I've checked that the tables are using the same charset and type in MySQL. I've also checked if the problem is just at the frontend but my debugger already shows me that the variable contains the questionmark symbols.

This is the code that's getting the data from the database

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $resObj[] = $obj;
        }
} else return false;
return $resObj;
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but I don't know what.

EDIT: the tables in phpMyAdmin show the correct characters, so they get inserted correctly.

Comment: Make sure your database charset is in UTF-8

Comment: is your connection in UTF-8?

Comment: Hmm, i guess it wasn't, mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8") fixed it... 
I still don't understand why this was only an issue for 1 table.

Comment: Maybe only 1 table had data that needed UTF8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So… have not had time to verify this, but it looks like the problem might have to do with [`SET CHARACTER SET <charset>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html). This command will associate the character set to [the collation of the default database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection).

If you are calling `<db-name>.highlights` and then not specifying a DB for `articles`, then this could, at least in theory, be causing the discrepancy. Meanwhile `mysqli_set_charset($conn, <charset>)` calls the directive `SET NAMES <charset>`. [This sets all of the collation and connection information to match `<charset>`.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html)

There are a number of settings [you can update in `my.cnf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800457/updating-variables-in-my-cnf) which could help address this problem in the future (such as setting the default collation for all DBs and updating the [collation database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection) value), but you're safer by explicitly setting this in PHP. Explicit is better than implicit and all that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is a issue before the data is written to db. You should check your php code. As a first step try to convert the charset of the already existent data.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

pls consider to make a backup before.

Comment: you edited your question, so maybe my answer is already obsolete.

Comment: No they just added a EDIT stating that their table in PHPmyAdmin were showing the correct charset for their data

Comment: I gave it a try anyways but it didn't change the situation, thanks anyway!